# Nikola + Pandoc + Mathjax: Math not displayed properly

Tags: pandoc, mathjax, nikola

I have a static site with Nikola in which `.md` are turned into `.html` with `pandoc`.

Part of my `conf.py` looks like:

```
COMPILERS = {
    # "markdown": ('.md', '.mdown', '.markdown'),
    "pandoc": ('.md', '.mdown', '.markdown')
}
```

I generate posts using `nikola new_post -f pandoc`.

My question is about generating Maths. I have a `.md` file like this:

```
<!--
.. title: Testing Maths
.. slug: testing-maths
.. date: 2015-07-04 23:44:07 UTC+08:00
.. tags: 
.. category: 
.. link: 
.. description: 
.. type: text
-->

$\beta_i=2$
$k_i=2$
$\hat{\beta_i}=2$
```

I build my site with `nikola build` and host it locally with `nikola serve`. And here's a screenshot of the browser:

[result http://s9.postimg.org/70t4j7k6l/Screen_Shot_2015_07_04_at_11_48_40_pm.png](http://s9.postimg.org/70t4j7k6l/Screen_Shot_2015_07_04_at_11_48_40_pm.png)

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the html source?

Comment: Yes sure. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/ddmmcjmm/52c469c47e6ab3429597

Comment: As far as I can see, Mathjax is not loaded at all. I don't know Nicola but I'm guessing something needs to add the --mathjax flag to the pandoc call.